# phoenix framework custom channels

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Im looking for a way to implement custom channels in the phoenix framework  I don't want to use the topics but do routing based on payload.

For example i have a json message like this

```
{
    "command":"hello",
    "payload": {
                 "message_id":"001",
                 "body":"is it me your looking for"
               }
    }
}
```

and want to do routing based on the value of "command", and i have no clue where to start. i can not send topics because i want to use a existing api.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by implementing your own Transport serializer (https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/master/lib/phoenix/transports/serializer.ex) and translating your client message format to the `%Phoenix.Socket.Message{}` format with topic, event, payload. See the built-in websocket serializer as a starting point for adaptation: 
https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/master/lib/phoenix/transports/websocket_serializer.ex

Comment: The only example is the websocket implementation, but it follows the behavior and should get you 75% of the way to your implementation